# The ultimate target of a multi-part css selector

Tags: css

HTML

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want the ultimate target of this train of selectors to be `<li>five</li>`? FWIW, no purple shows anywhere.

```
ul > li + ol > li {
    /*
        nested lists
    */

    background-color: purple;   /* just for testing */
}
```

Isn't the order of searching left to right?

> 1. (ul>li)
> 2. (ul>li) + ol
> 3. ((ul>li) + ol) > li

If so, isn't the ultimate target `<li>five</li>` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ol` is a *child* of `li`, not a sibling.

```css
ul > li > ol > li {
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector to select the exact element.

```css
ul li ol li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```